# CalendarDateSelect Error Ruby 1.9.3 Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

Essentially every web page that loads in my application, gives me this error first:

> CalendarDateSelect Error: Prototype could not be found. Please make sure that your application's layout includes prototype.js (.g. <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>) *before* it includes calendar_date_select.js (.g. <%= calendar_date_select_includes %>).

I found calendar_date_select in my Views/layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb file and saw that indeed my prototype.js comes before calendar_date_select. Here is a part of my file:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>

<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, 'tablekit', 'calendar_date_select/calendar_date_select', 'calendar_date_select/format_american' %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/noprint.css', :media => 'print' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'calendar_date_select/default', :media => 'screen' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'calendar_date_select' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "date" %> .....
```

Not sure how to resolve this issue. Any suggestions would be most useful.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have the 'prototype-rails' gem, which takes care of the above functionality.
I had just the 'prototype' gem, which I am not sure what it is.